# Refresh Table View Data does not work

Tags: uitableview, xcode4, reloaddata

I have a UITableView, named Favorites section. If i add an entry to the favorites section, i can see it loaded correctly in the favorites section, but if i continue and try to add another entry, it will only work if i go to favorites section, then the original section and then back to the favorites section, as if something is holding her from refreshing.

 I tried to put 
 [UiTableView reloadData]  in the viewWillAppear , but still no result. I even tried **[self.tableView reloadData]** and still. Any ideas what to do?

 Note that i am using a tab bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you have properly added your record in datasource, and after that only u have reloaded data.

You can just reload a section if you know in which section you are adding else, you can use insertRows method to just update new record in your table, reloading entire table for a row is bad practice.

Hope this helps